# VBA alternative to using the 'AND' function in excel with hh:mm formatted cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a vba alternative to using the 'AND' function within my workbook

currently I'm working with a timesheet style worksheet and I have a need to look into a column of data "K23:K117", set to hh:mm format,  which shows shift start times.

Based off the contents of the cell, say if CELL "K26" = a time between 06:00-21:00 then "L26" = MWD Midweek days else its MWN Midweek nights

I've tried using the 'AND' function however it doesn't seem to like the hh:mm time format

Comment: `And` is just a logic gate using TRUE/FALSE. If it isn't returning the results you expect, then your terms are incorrect. However we can't help with that as you have not posted any code. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The date format does not matter for any comparison... Please, specify what kind of data exists in the column to be processed. Only time? `hh:mm:ss` or `Date`, something as `mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: Thanks both. I don't have any code yet as I've never tried to do a comparative exercise like this.

Comment: the formula i've tried is 
=IF(AND(K23>=500,K23<=2100),"MWD","MWN")

Comment: Try: `=IF(AND(K23>=TIMEVALUE("05:00"),K23<=TIMEVALUE("21:00")),"MWD","MWN")`

Comment: @CLR One of those should be without an equal sign (probably the 2nd one: `...K23<TIME...`), so `21:00` would be categorized under `MWN`.

Comment: That solution works perfectly CLR

Comment: @VBasic2008 - you're right of course, I assumed OPs logic was correct. Chances are times of exactly 9pm should be MWN - `=IF(AND(K23>=TIMEVALUE("05:00"),K23<TIMEVALUE("21:00")),"MWD","MWN")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulas ar easier to be understood (and use), but they load Excel consuming its resources and in case of big size they show down even simple operations.

If this is the case of your workbook, the next VBA code will do the job fast and without workbook load. Anyhow, you required a VBA solution:

```
Sub ShiftsExtraction()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, i As Long
 Dim minTime As Double: minTime = CDbl(TimeValue("05:00"))
 Dim maxTime As Double: maxTime = CDbl(TimeValue("21:00"))
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("K" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 
 arr = sh.Range("K2:L" & lastR).Value2

 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If (arr(i, 1) - Int(arr(i, 1))) >= minTime And _
                     (arr(i, 1) - Int(arr(i, 1))) < maxTime Then
        arr(i, 2) = "MWD"
    Else
        arr(i, 2) = "MWN"
    End If
 Next i

 'drop back the processed array content:
 sh.Range("K2").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value2 = arr
End Sub
```

It works if only time exists in "K:K" column or `Date` plus time. Only the time is taken in consideration...